# .NET Core auto executável

Tags: linux, .net-core, .exe

Após criar minha primeira aplicação console com .NET Core no Windows 10 com Visual Studio 2017 copiei para meu servidor **Linux - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS** (já com o .NET Core instalado).

Executei com sucesso o comando:

Windows

```
> dotnet minhaApp.dll
```

Linux

```
$ dotnet minhaApp.dll
```

Agora quero ter um **executável independente**, sem precisar do `dotnet` para executar. Como faço?

Desejo executar assim:

Windows

```
> minhaApp.exe
```

Linux

```
$ ./minhaApp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não muda quase nada. Normalmente você deve *setar* usando como alvo uma versão do próprio .NET Core. O que muda é especificar onde vai rodar.

Para o Windows basta dar este comando:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

Para o Linux basta mudar o alvo, mas nunca fiz, provavelmente `ubuntu.16.04-x64` ([veja o catálogo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Antes precisa configurar o `csproj` para os alvos desejados, algo assim:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64/RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

O resto é igual ao que você já sabe fazer.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para **Linux** funcionou, alvo **ubuntu.16.04-x64** e depois permissão para executar: **chmod +x minhaApp**. Se desejar inclua na sua resposta.

Comment: Permissão independe deste processo, é algo da execução de qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o próprio Visual Studio, clique com o botão direito no projeto que deve ter o executável gerado e depois em **Publicar**. Não basta apenas fazer o build.

[image: Publicar]

Depois clique em editar e defina o destino do executável. Então clique em publicar.

[image: Definir destino]